# Python checking if a point is in sphere with center x, y ,z

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if a point is within a sphere with a center point of (x, y, z) where (x, y, z) is not (0, 0, 0).

This code I'm using to generate the points I want to check:

```
def generatecoords(self, i):
    x, y, z = generatepoint()

    if i >= 1:
        valid = False

        while valid == False:
            coords = self.checkpoint(x, y, z)

            for b in world.starlist:
                if coords == world.starlist[b].coords:
                    coords = self.checkpoint(x, y, z)

                else:
                    valid = True

    else:
        coords = self.checkpoint(x, y, z)

    return coords

def checkpoint(self, x, y, z):
    d = math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)

    while d >= self.radius:
        x, y, z = generatepoint()
        d = math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)

    coords = (int(x), int(y), int(z))

    return coords

def generatepoint():
    x, y, z = [int(random.uniform(-self.radius, self.radius)) \
               for b in range(3)]

    return x, y, z
```

These function are called in a for loop to generate the points in a dictionary, while also checking the unlikely chance that points aren't placed on top of another(mostly because I can).

I trying to figure out what I need to add to `math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)` so that it accounts for a center that isn't `(0, 0, 0)`. I do know of one way to do it, but it would require several lines of code and I'd rather do it in one. I would have asked this in the comments of the answer in another question, but I'm not allowed to comment on answers yet.

Comment: Does math.sqrt((x-a) **2 + (y-b) **2 + (z-c) **2) give you some help (a,b,c)? [being the sphere center coordinates]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The formula is:

A point **(x,y,z)** is inside the sphere with center **(cx,cy,cz)** and radius **r** if

```
 (x - cx)^2 + (y - cy)^2 + (z - cz)^2 < r^2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very short function that returns `True` if the point is in the sphere, and `False` if not.

The inputs are two numpy arrays: `point = [x,y,z]` and `ref = [x,y,z]` and the radius should be a `float`.

```
import numpy as np

def inSphere(self, point, ref, radius):

    # Calculate the difference between the reference and measuring point
    diff = np.subtract(point, ref)

    # Calculate square length of vector (distance between ref and point)^2
    dist = np.sum(np.power(diff, 2))

    # If dist is less than radius^2, return True, else return False
    return dist < radius ** 2
```